# HttpGet in Breeze controller sees my dbset as the method with the same name

Tags: breeze, asp.net-web-api

I'm using EF and WebAPI. This is the code:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IQueryable<adj_run> adj_run()
    {
        return _contextProvider.Context.adj_run;
    }
```

The message is:

```
'PortalDataClassLibrary.BreezeAPIController.adj_run()' is a 'method' but is used like a 'type'
```

This is my DbSet:

```
public virtual DbSet<adj_run> adj_run { get; set; }
```

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: What does your client side query look like?

Comment: ... and take a look at this link to see if its a  similar issue. http://forums.asp.net/t/1067013.aspx

Comment: I found the problem. I had not included my DbSet folder in the other project.